# DATE_FORMAT MYSQL Not Formatting Like It Should Be

Tags: mysql, date, time, date-format

I need some insights as to why I'm not getting the desired format for my date.

Link: **removed**

Table and Data

```
+-------+---------------+     +--------+-----------------------+
| id    | primary, int  |     +    1   |  2015-10-01 10:23:33  |
| dated | timestamp     |     +    2   |  2015-10-02 10:30:31  |
+-------+---------------+     +--------+-----------------------+
```

Sql

```
Select id, DATE_FORMAT(dated, "%Y-%m-%d") as dated from table
```

Desired output :

```
+-------+---------------+
| 1     | 2015-10-01    |
| 2     | 2015-10-02    |
+-------+---------------+
```

But I get this:

```
+-------+-----------------------+
| 1     | 2015-10-01 00:00:00   |
| 2     | 2015-10-02 00:00:00   |
+-------+-----------------------+
```

Thank you.

Comment: Something is turning the result back to a datetime.  How are you showing the value?

Comment: @GordonLinoff just putting it in a variable.   $var = $result
edit: it's laravel, i'm using eloquent

Comment: You are probably putting it in a variable that is a datetime or that is being printed out as a datetime.  The value from SQL is a string and would not contain hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: meaning to say, if my field is date (timestamp) and using it as the name my derived value, the date's format is still being used for the result?

edit, so the date's format is overriding the for the formatted.

Comment: I don't *think* it has to do with the name, but it is possible.  Perhaps the application tool you are using interpret strings that look like dates as datetime values.

Comment: just changed it, and yeah, it's overriding.. i just need to change to alias to different name..

thanks for your time gordon linoff.

Comment: @JadeBaribar Maybe you could answer your own question by specifying that your MySQL editor is converting the result back into a timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is still using the format of the field for the derived format when using the same field name as your alias.

Solution: Changed the alias to other name.